# Can you insert an opportunity without an account with APEX?

Tags: apex, opportunity, account

I always thought that Opportunity had a Master-Detail relationship with Account. Which means that you aren't able to create an Opportunity without an Account.

Today I ran apex code to create an Opportunity. It did not have AccountId set. So I expected it to not execute the code. Lo and behold, the Opportunity was created. If I then want to edit the opportunity, I can't save it because of the standard Salesforce settings which require an Account for an Opportunity.

I executed the following code:

```
        //Create an Opportunity
    Opportunity testOpportunity = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opp', CloseDate = Date.today(), StageName = 'Qualification');
    insert testOpportunity;
```

Comment: Please include the error message verbatim. Also, any org could implement Validation Rules which require an Account.

Comment: There is no error message because it's not failing. Like I mentioned: But I noticed today that I am able to insert an Opportunity without an Account through Execute Anonymous Window.

Comment: *"Once you want to edit the Opportunity it will tell you that you can't save it because there's no Account related to the Opportunity."* Can you please **[edit]** your post to be a bit more clear about what behavior you observe and where you are confused?

Comment: I thought it was clear that this wasn't the part of the question I was curious about. The main question was, can you insert an opportunity without an account, which I thought was impossible. I hope that makes it clear why I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `Opportunity.AccountId` field is a `Lookup`. You can create an `Opportunity` record which has no `Account`. Here's what you get when you debug `Opportunity.AccountId.getDescribe()`:

> Schema.DescribeFieldResult[getByteLength=18;getCalculatedFormula=null;getCompoundFieldName=null;getController=null;getDefaultValue=null;getDefaultValueFormula=null;getDigits=0;getFilteredLookupInfo=null;getInlineHelpText=null;getLabel=Account ID;getLength=18;getLocalName=AccountId;getMask=null;getMaskType=null;getName=AccountId;getPrecision=0;getReferenceTargetField=null;getRelationshipName=Account;getRelationshipOrder=null;getScale=0;getSoapType=ID;getSobjectField=AccountId;getType=REFERENCE;isAccessible=true;isAggregatable=true;isAutoNumber=false;isCalculated=false;isCascadeDelete=false;isCaseSensitive=false;isCreateable=true;isCustom=false;isDefaultedOnCreate=false;isDependentPicklist=false;isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;isDisplayLocationInDecimal=false;isEncrypted=false;isExternalId=false;isFilterable=true;isGroupable=true;isHighScaleNumber=false;isHtmlFormatted=false;isIdLookup=false;isNameField=false;isNamePointing=false;isNillable=true;isPermissionable=true;isQueryByDistance=false;isRestrictedDelete=false;isSearchPrefilterable=true;isSortable=true;isUnique=false;isUpdateable=true;isWriteRequiresMasterRead=false;]

Specifically, `getRelationshipOrder` returns `null`, whereas if the relationship were `Master-Detail`, it would be either `0` or `1`.